# How to store strcat value in another variable

Tags: c

> `stringCat(char a[], char b[], char out[])` The `stringCat` function takes two strings and concats them and outputs them to array `out`. Assume that `out` has enough space to hold contents of both `a` and `b`. Implement the function.

Comment: What is your question? What is your problem? What have you tried yourself? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And don't forget how to [edit] your questions, or how to create a [mre].

Comment: Better as `stringCat (char *out, const char *a, const char *b);` as the first argument is generally the *Destination* in all string functions. You could always just do `strcpy (out, a);` then `strcat (out, b);`

Comment: @जलजनक: good point, but I like to crunch some pointers for breakfast :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function `stringCat` can be written very simply:

```
#include <string.h>

char *stringCat(const char a[], const char b[], char out[]) {
    return strcat(strcpy(out, a), b);
}
```

To avoid scanning the first string twice, you can implement it explicitly with pointers:

```
char *stringCat(const char a[], const char b[], char out[]) {
    char *p = out;
    while ((*p = *a++) != '\0')
        p++;
    while ((*p = *b++) != '\0')
        p++;
    return out;
}
```

Both implementations here above assume that the array pointed to by `out` has enough space for the concatenated string, including a null terminator. It might be safer to allocate this array and let the caller free the memory after use:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *stringCat(const char a[], const char b[]) {
    size_t alen = strlen(a);
    size_t blen = strlen(b);
    char *out = malloc(alen + blen + 1);
    if (out) {
        memcpy(out, a, alen);
        memcpy(out + alen, b, blen + 1);
    }
    return out;
}
```